# "ConnectException: Connection timed out" even if the URL works in the browser

Tags: java, networking

I'm working on a project and I need to connect to a server to load a URL. I try to connect to this URL via a Java connection as follows:

```
url = new URL (URLPath); 
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();
```

But I get the following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

I looked at all the solutions already mentioned on the forum but I did not found a solution to my problem.

When I test the URL in my browser: works perfectly. This is not the case with my Java code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it's not written in English (even by stackoverflow's standards ;-)

Comment: @ammoQ: It is however a bit racist that SO prefers English over other languages. It would be nice if there was some feature to translate questions between users (for instance using Google translate). ;)

Comment: Ok . This is the translation :)
Hello there,

I am a young Java developer. I'm working on a project, I need to connect to a server to load a URL. I try to connect to this url by Java connection as follows:

      url = new URL (URLPath);

      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();

But I get the following error:

      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

I looked in all the solutions already mentioned in the forum but I did not found a solution to my problem.

Since I test the URL in my browser: works perfectly. This is not the case with my Java code.

Comment: There are several possibilities. Possible the server is indeed only reachable by a proxy, or perhaps the server uses a robot blocking tool. You can avoid this by adding additional meta-data to your connection to act as if you are firefox...

Comment: @CommuSoft, how the heck is this _racism_ when it has nothing to do with _race_? Or are you insinuating that some races can't learn English? :-) _Racism_ gotta be one of the most misused and abused words. And speaking favoring only one thing, why Google Translate and not Bing Translate, perhaps? :-)

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem.
The solution is: my url contains a secure https connection, which is not supported by my code.
I tried to find the right http url to connect, which is worked.

Comment: @mohamProgrammer, then please add that as an answer and accept it after a couple of days, so that the question doesn't remain without an accepted answer.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Sorry, in my country everything you say against a "minority" is classified as racism.

Comment: @CommuSoft, that would be _discrimination_ as far as I know, but the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/) might now better.

Comment: *now* -> *know*. It is indeed *discrimination*. The first post was of course merely intended as a joke, although I think it would be nice if you are, let's say a Chinese native speaker that there was some functionality to translate your question in English and for a German to translate that question in German if it isn't that clear. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
I solved the problem.
The solution is: my `url` contains a secure `https connection`, which is not supported by my `code in Eclipse`.
I tried to find the right `http url to connect`, which is worked.

Have a nice day :) .

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, try this one-

```
   import java.net.*;
   import java.io.*;

  public class URLConnectionReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
  }

 }
```

Comment: En fait, j'utilise le même code. Mon code fonctionne pour un Url mais il ne fonctionne pas pour d'autres !!

Comment: Sorry my dear friend i don't understand french.!

Comment: @mohamProgrammer: If you have control over the client, perhaps you should `flush` data regularly.

Comment: Ok My Friend. In fact, I use the same code. My code works for a Url but it does not work for others!

Comment: @mohamProgrammer: What is the average delay for that server. You can perform benchmarks with `ping`.

Comment: I try to ping to the server but it not works. However, it works with my browser.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem.
The solution is: my url contains a secure https connection, which is not supported by my code.
I tried to find the right http url to connect, which is worked.

Answer (score 0):

quite possibly, your browser is configured with a proxy.
the destination may not be reachable directly.

regards,
Gerard

Comment: Yes, my browser is configured with a dynamic proxy that works.
This is the same case for my Eclipse.

Comment: @mohamProgrammer: Is the site still reachable without a proxy?

Comment: Non. But the browser in set to a dynamic proxy. http://proxy:8080/ .    So the browser choose a proxy from a list of proxies.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem.
The solution is: my url contains a secure https connection, which is not supported by my code.
I tried to find the right http url to connect, which is worked.